# How can I map different keys to same value but declare them only once?

Tags: regex, perl, hash, scripting

Is it possible to map different keys to the same value in a hash but using only 1 "slot"?
E.g. if I have the following:

```
my %hash = (  
   person => A,  
   persons => A,  
   employee => C,  
   employees => C,  
   desk => X,  
);
```

Can I make it somehow like:

```
my %hash = (  
   person|persons => A,   
   employee|employees => C,  
   desk => X,  
);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: It certainly is possible; your second code snippet would compile if you quoted properly. You might get better solutions if you explain *why* you want to do this, though.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot it would run but not give the desired result. At least, not as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:Why?But to be able to allow flexibility in the key usage in case of typo

Comment: @Jim In that case, you don't need to restrict yourself to a single key. Your first snippet achieves that goal just fine. [Qtax's solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21415902/176646) have the same end result (i.e. multiple keys per base word) with less typing.

Comment: Avoid typos with `use warnings`? You can even [use warnings as fatal errors](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html#Fatal-Warnings).

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "one slot". Do you want both to change if one is changed?

Comment: @ikegami:that is a good question. The keys should be interchangeable, so yes

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any built in syntax which is like that. But you can always do:

```
my %hash;
$hash{employee} = $hash{employees} = 'C';
```

Or even:

```
my %hash;
@hash{qw( employee employees )} = ('C') x 2; # or ('C', 'C'); or qw(C C);
```

Comment: Would the down voter like to comment? I'd like to know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in syntax for that, but you could use a little helper function:

```
sub make_hash {
    my @result;
    while (my ($key, $value) = splice @_, 0, 2) {
        push @result, $_, $value for split /\|/, $key;
    }
    return @result;
}
```

Then you could say:

```
my %hash = make_hash(
    'person|persons' => 'A',
    'employee|employees' => 'C',
    desk => 'X',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question and solutions [posted over on perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=34267) where (IMO) the best solution goes like this:

```
my %hash = map { my $item = pop @$_; map { $_, $item } @$_ }
[qw(HELP ?) => sub { ... }],
[qw(QUIT EXIT LEAVE) => sub { ... }],
...;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is unclear to me but, maybe an aproach
where you use an intermediate "alias" hash would work.

Then access values through %categories to reach a value in %hash

```
my %categories = (  
 person => people,  
 persons => people,  
 employee => worker,  
 employees => worker,  
 desk => furniture,
 chair => furniture,
);

my %hash = (  
   people => A,  
   worker => C,  
   furniture => X,  
);
```